# Who can send me a skype package?

Tags: skype

I live in China and now want to download skype from skype.com, but the web cannot open. I have tried many websites to download the package but none of them worked. It seems that skype is not popular with u-know-who...WHO CAN SEND ME A PACKAGE BY EMAIL!HELP![email hidden]. THANKS!

Comment: Can't you use a proxy?

Comment: I'm sorry about your situation, but I don't think we would be able to help here :(.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: quite likely he can't - China is a bit, um, restrictive.

Comment: @RolandTaylor you wouldn't help even if it where legal... as much as you hate skype :=P

Comment: @TheX: :D that's true too lol

Comment: Only way I see it working out is finding a working tor bridge.  Even then, the skype traffic might be blocked after it is installed(and piping skype over tor is a no-go).

Answer (score 3):

I've just uploaded [the 32-bit version](http://www.speedyshare.com/files/28025948/skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.25-1_i386.deb) for you.